# Printing information of a loop

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner

I need help printing out the information of this loop after it is all complete.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= activityCount; i++) {
            int[] intActivites = new int[activityCount];
            int arrayLength = intActivites.length;
            System.out.println("Select time for activity #" + i);
            System.out.println("Write name for activity #" + i);
            int activityTime = sc.nextInt();
            addTime = sc.nextLine();
            if (addTime.equals(addTime)) {
                String timeActivity = sc.nextLine();
                String all = timeActivity + " @ " + activityTime + ":00";
                System.out.println(all);
            }
        }
```

I need help setting the activities and activity times to a string named schedule

Comment: `if (addTime.equals(addTime))` when would that condition ever be `false`?

Comment: I don't think it would

Comment: There is no such string in your code example. What have you tried to build it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we ignore the logic of this loop. If all you need is to log all events from the loop in one log message when the loop exits then:

1. You could append your event messages to a StringBuffer initialized before the loop and print the StringBuffer after the loop. This String buffer could be made `final` to avoid the loop re-initializing it
2. You could also consider using a logging framework like log4J, SLF4J or Logback to log these events to a file/ console

Looking at the logic in your code-snippet, I assume you want the user to enter what activity they want to do in a given hour (indicated by the integer input). In the end you would want to print out the entire plan as entered by the user.

With that view this is not just a log message this is actually a summary that you want to show to the user of your program or persist it in a data-store. You can use approach #1 mentioned above.

Hope this helps :)

Edit: Adding Source Code here

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {

  Map<Integer, String> timeSlots;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main app = new Main();
    app.startApp(4);
  }

  public void startApp(int numberOfActivities) {
    timeSlots = new HashMap();
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
      for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfActivities; i++) {
        Integer activityTime = getActivityTime(i, sc);
        if (isTimeSlotAvailable(activityTime)) {
          timeSlots.put(activityTime, getActivityName(i, sc));
        } else {
          System.out.println("Time slot [" + activityTime + "] is already used.");
        }
      }
    }
    printTimeSlots();
  }

  private void printTimeSlots() {
    timeSlots.keySet().forEach(activityTime -> printTimeSlot(activityTime, timeSlots.get(activityTime)));
  }

  private void printTimeSlot(Integer time, String activity) {
    System.out.println(activity + " @ " + time + ":00");
  }

  private boolean isTimeSlotAvailable(Integer activityTime) {
    return (timeSlots.get(activityTime) == null);
  }

  private Integer getActivityTime(int i, Scanner sc) {
    System.out.println("Enter time for activity #" + i);
    return Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
  }

  private String getActivityName(int i, Scanner sc) {
    System.out.println("Enter name of activity #" + i);
    return sc.nextLine();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How would I do the first method that you mentioned? I am a beginner programmer and don't really know what the meaning of a StringBuffer or how it could be made final.

Comment: Edited the Answer to add code that you needed. I have made some assumptions but you can get the general idea. Let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. You don't know how much this helped.